# Convergence or divergence of the sum series with $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(1-2^{1/n})^6}{(n+3)^p}$, $p\in \Bbb R$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am stuck on finding the convergence or divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-2^{1/n})^6}{(n+3)^p}$$ depending on p with p being in R. I tried to compare it and say its general term is smaller than $$\frac{1}{{(n+3)^p}}$$ and then consider that $$\frac{1}{{(n+3)^p}}$$ is convergent for ( p > 1 ) (comparing it with a harmonic series), so the given series is convergent for ( p > 1 ).

I attempted to use the logarithmic criterion to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-2^{1/n})^6$$ is divergent (I don t think I calculated the limit correctly). Then, using the limit comparison test with $$(1-2^{1/n})^6$$, I obtained that the given series is divergent for ( p <= 0 ).

I think that my approach is flawed since I still haven't determined the nature of the series for ( 0 < p <= 1 ).

Answer (score 2):

lets use integral test
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{(1-2^\frac{1}{x})^6}{(x+3)^p} dx$$
put $y=\frac{1}{x}$ then we get the integral
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{y^{p-2}}{(3y+1)^p} (1-2^y)^6 dy=\int_0^1 \frac{y^{p+4}}{(3y+1)^p} \left(\frac{1-2^y}{y}\right)^6 dy $$
for the function
$$f(y)=\frac{y^{p+4}}{(3y+1)^p} \left(\frac{1-2^y}{y}\right)^6  $$
its defined for $y\in(0,1]$  and $\lim_{y \to 0} f(y)$ does exist only if $p>-4$

for that the integral is converge for $p+1>-4$ So the series converge for $p>-5$

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geq1$, it can be shown by Maclaurin series of $2^x$ that$\frac{\ln2}n<2^{\frac1n}-1<\frac{2\ln2}n$. Therefore the given series has the same character of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^6(n+3)^p}$. İt converges for $p+6>1$.